# How to deploy a completed Django application to an existing apache server?

Tags: django, apache, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

I have installed python and django, both are tested and working now. I wanted to download a Django app from *https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-lfs/0.7.7#downloads* and then install it on a web server. After I unzip the tarball file, what directive I should upload them to? the django project folder created by running "python-admin.py startproject myprojectname" ? do I need to edit some files inside the app file? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The instructions are on the LFS documentation site (http://docs.getlfs.com/en/latest/introduction/installation.html)....

```
Download the installer from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-lfs
$ tar xzf django-lfs-installer-<version>.tar.gz
$ cd lfs-installer
$ python bootstrap.py
$ bin/buildout -v
Enter your database settings to lfs_project/settings.py
$ bin/django syncdb
$ bin/django migrate
$ bin/django lfs_init
$ bin/django collectstatic
$ bin/django runserver
Browse to http://localhost:8000
```

You will likely have to install either mysql or postgresql on your server and then edit lfs_project/settings.py accordingly.

I was looking through the various url.py within the lfs app and they look quite extensive.  If you want to integrate these with your app, it might be better to start with LFS and then build your stuff in, rather than vice versa.

Comment: I read this tuturial before, but I didn't want to use buildout method.  i downloaded the full package other than installer(270k). thank you all the same.